# Azure APIM Fails CORS Preflight, How Can I Force APIM to Respond with the Correct CORS Headers for Preflight?

Tags: azure, web, azure-functions, cors, azure-api-management

The CORS for Post Requests, where there aren't any preflight checks, are working just fine for APIM, but whenever I need a GET request, APIM fails the preflight and only responds with the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 28 Jul 2023 03:17:03 GMT
Cache-Control: private
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:xxxxxx
```

I have tried editing the global policy to allow for CORS requests, but it has failed to do anything. This is what my current global policy with CORS looks like.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <cors allow-credentials="false">
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>*</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
            <expose-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </expose-headers>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request />
    </backend>
    <outbound />
    <on-error />
</policies>
```

I just need the preflight to respond with the correct CORS headers so I can make the calls to the backend. As I mentioned, it is not a problem with the backend, as when I send requests that don't require the preflight, they work just fine. Even when I convert some GET requests that have the CORS issue to POST requests, they work, but this is not a desired solution.

None of the solutions found in other posts I've found have worked either.

Comment: GET calls are generally not accompanied by preflight OPTIONS call, instead they include Origin header and APIM would be expected to reply with appropriate CORS headers. Could you provide GET and POST samples of your requests as they're sent by browser and response you get?